# Градиент для статус бара

Tags: android, xml, gui, material-design

[image]

Статус бар в макете так же градиентный, пробовал просто цвет подогнать монотонный - не подходит, и дизайнера не устраивает.

Предложили использовать темно-серый, но вдруг можно.

Так можно ли в андроиде реализовать подобный функционал?

Ps. картинки больше найти не удалось, но надеюсь здесь всё видно.

Comment: возможное решение на enSO http://stackoverflow.com/a/36907967/5634351

Comment: @KirillStoianov да, там действительно неплохой вариант - но с заменой тулбара на свою разметку, насколько я понимаю?Есть ли еще способы осуществить подобное, потому как в главной активити иконка-гамбургер, и заменять везде тулбары что-то костыль совсем нещадный.

Comment: а если сделать все тоже самое с обычным туллбаром?

Comment: @KirillStoianov действительно, не подумал. Оформи как ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сделать градиентный статус бар можно,  установив для него полупрозрачноть

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        Window w = getWindow();
        w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        w.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
    }
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

создать `drawable` с градиентом и установить его как `background` в `toolbar`

**gradient_drawable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:angle="135" android:startColor="#f56f2c" android:endColor="#fa9f46"/>
</shape>
```